# Drupal - Migrating to new server

Tags: drupal, migration

I have a fairly new drupal installation with a few hundred nodes. I moved it from the development server to the production server.

However, when I opened my homepage, it says page not found. After checking all my links, it seems that I can't get to any of my content. They exist in the node database, as well as the content type tables. I verified that all my URL aliases are also in place. In most cases, I can still see all the information from views I had created, but when clicking to see the full node view, I get the "Page not found".

I did trim all my cache tables before importing to reduce the size of the DB. Has anyone had these symptoms before? Perhaps there is a particular table, that when truncated, will lead to this problem?

**Update: Imported my revision table again, and presto - Although my content came back, I'm still having a sort of permissions problem. When an anonymous visitor comes to the site, they are told they don't have permission to see items like content type "Page", yet in user permissions, everything looks good (definitely good before migration) perhaps another deleted table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, node content information is in the revisions table, not the node table. You REALLY need the revisions table. I assume you can just remigrate again, this time without truncating revisions.

Comment: It was indeed the revision table. Hmmm..I was actually sort of ignorant to the this table. I thought it only came into play when revisions were requested. I do all sorts of custom scripting, all pointing at the "node" table. I wonder if I am missing something. Also - although my content came back, I'm still having a sort of permissions problem. When an anonymous visitor comes to the site, they are told they don't have permission to see items like content type "Page", yet in user permissions, everything looks good (definitely good before migration) perhaps another deleted table? Anyway, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if table is broken, it shouldn't show "Page not found". It may show that sql error that table or column doesn't exists.
Try troubleshoot in http://drupal.org/node/201875 (you will see Page Not Found links in middle). 
Also may be you use some redirecting in your node theming, check this.

p.s. In any case, node saving touch 2 tables: node and node_revisions